# Adding Cidoc Sphinx theme to my documentation

Tags: git

I am following instructions given [here](https://github.com/adrianmacneil/cidoc)

I get the following error when entering $ git submodule add git@github.com:adrianmacneil/cidoc.git user_guide_src/_themes/cidoc in the terminal:

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Help?

Comment: Is your add-on in a git repo?

Comment: No it is not - should it be for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adrian may have a better answer, but this works for me...

If your add-on is not a Git repository, of if you would rather install the theme manually rather than as a submodule, you can just download the theme from Github and put it in your Sphinx documentation setup.

Just make sure your `conf.py` file has the correct path to the theme.

So if your documentation setup looks like this:

[image]

You'd have this in your `conf.py`

```
html_theme_path = ['_themes']
html_theme = 'cidoc'
```

If you aren't already familiar with Sphinx I found this to be a really helpful guide: [Easy and beautiful documentation with Sphinx.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-sphinx-documentation/index.html) Along with the official doc's [First Steps with Sphinx.](http://sphinx-doc.org/tutorial.html)

Thanks to Adrian for making this available!

Comment: Alex - your directory structure was very helpful for me to get my bearings. Then I went ahead and signed up for github, cloned the repo, downloaded the mac package and worked my way through the instructions - sweet - but staying local for now. Thanks again