# How is the ExpressionEngine user guide documentation managed? By categories or channels with relationship fields to the child pages?

Tags: categories, relationships, channel, structure, wiki

I would like to create a user guide for my website which functions the same way as the ExpressionEngine user guide / docs. Seen [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/).

I would like to know how they structure their pages. Do they use categories, if so how? Or do they use 1 channel for the parent articles with a relationship field pointing at another channel for the child articles?

Do they use an add-on ? I was also thinking that they may have used a customised version of the [ExpressionEngine Wiki](https://github.com/EllisLab/Wiki) to achieve the user guides?

I tried Googling it but came across nothing. What do you think the best approach would be in creating such a thing?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Last I heard (some years ago), it was all handled via Sphinx: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/ No idea if that's still true though.

Comment: This was definitely the case. See [this answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/6467/22) for more info. There is actually a [Sphinx theme](https://github.com/amacneil/cidoc) that matched the previous EE docs design. Sphinx is a pretty cool way to generate docs.